# The range for the matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra

If a matrix $B$ has full rank by columns, can we conclude
that $rg (AB) = rg (A)$? And what $rg (BA) = rg (A)$? The matrices $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily square, in addition it must be taken into account that full rank by columns means that the range of $B$ is equal to its number of columns.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you are talking about the image. Let's assume that $A$ and $B$ are $n$-dimensional, then yes $rg(AB) = rg(A)$. This comes from the fact that you have $Ax= ABy,$ where $y = B^{-1}x.$

The other equality is wrong. Take

$$
B = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \end{array} \right) 
$$

$$A = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \end{array} \right) 
$$

Then,

$$BA = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \end{array} \right) 
$$

Clearly, $rg(BA) \neq rg(A)$

Comment: Your affirmation is correct when $B$ is a non-singular matrix, however we cannot guarantee that $B$ has an inverse, since the hypothesis says that it is full range by columns, that is, that the range is equal to the number of $B$ columns and we can not specify that $B$ is a square matrix.

Comment: I think we should think about the statement in the more general situation where $ B \in M_{n \times m}(R) $ and $A \in M_ {p \times n}(R)$.

Comment: if $m >n$, this will work too. However, if $n>m$, this is not true. Take $A=I_2$, then $rg(A) = R^2$. Take $B$ as column vector (n=2, m=1), for example $(1,1)^t$, then $rg(AB) = \alpha (1,1)^t$

Comment: I understand your counterexample for the $n>m$ case, however it is not yet clear to me why the statement for the $m>n$ case is valid.

Comment: This is because dim(Rg(B)) = n, and therefore the range of B spans $R^n$